# asp.net to php encoding

Tags: php, asp.net

I need to do this with php encryption method.
turkey 3d a bank payment module in the code for the example given to me in this way encryption.
could you help me translate this into php code?

```
    SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] notHashedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(notHashedStr);
    byte[] hashedByte = sha1.ComputeHash(notHashedBytes);
    string hashedStr = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashedByte);
    return hashedStr;
```

Comment: i could be wrong but I think you need to include the SHA1CryptoServiceProvider() object

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about .Net but from what I gathered in [this page](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/SHA_checksum) seems like the PHP equivalent is just:

```
$hashedStr = base64_encode(sha1($notHashedStr, true));
```

You need to encode the raw binary format and not the hexadecimal representation.

Comment: @hakan: And it doesn't work? Also, could you post a dummy input string and the corresponding output hash?

Comment: i use this code `$hashedStr = base64_encode(sha1($notHashedStr));
` output hash not correct